# Scrollbar not resizing after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

I am working on a project where I have to show datatables.
My Problem is, that the Website loads in the tables and as there are a lot of rows in it the website has a really high hight.
Normally the height of the website gets rezised after the talbe is split into multiple pages. My Problem now is that the table is split into pages but the height of the page doesnt rezise automaticaly.

If I resize the window in chrome then the website heigt updates and everything works fine.

Anyone out there how knows what the problem might be?

Edit:

Here is a video showing what my problem is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7zqeB_dsUTVS1l6Q0xjOTF0RHc/view?usp=sharing
It is working just fine when opening the page in an HTML-File, but when I use a blade.php file with Laravel i get the error shown above.
I basically just need some code that reloads the height of the page.

Comment: Can you paste some of your code that is not working, so we understand the question.

Comment: Will do in a few hours when I have the computer in front of me

Comment: I edited the first post with more infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the html

give the body height 100vh

Comment: Ok, it worked. But I still don't understand why I needed to add that in order to get it working.